# check business status based on opening and closing time using php time function

Tags: php, time

Am trying to show business operation status based on the open and closing time they supply, but it seems not working even when i have follow few examples online.
Please i know that question may have been asked in different method, can someone assist me to fix this as the below function is showing closed even when business is open.

My php function

```
function OperationHours($open, $close){
    $status = 'closed';
    $current_time = date('h:iA');
    $nowTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $current_time);
    $openTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $open);
    $closeTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $close);
        if ($nowTime > $openTime && $nowTime < $closeTime){
            $status = 'open';
        }
    return $status;
}

/*function OperationHours($open, $close){
    $status = 'closed';
    $timestamp = time();
    $currentTime = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($timestamp);
    $openTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $open);
    $closeTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $close);
        if(($openTime < $currentTime) && ($currentTime < $closeTime)) {
            $status = 'open';
        }
    return $status;
}*/

echo OperationHours('09:00AM', '03:30AM');
```

Comment: Did you really mean to have a close time of 03:30 AM? I.e. before your opening time? Unless it's a bar or nightclub it's unusual - and your code doesn't take account of the fact that it will be the following day.

Comment: @Nick yes, is a club, can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a check whether the closing time belongs to the other day:

```
function OperationHours($open, $close){
    $status = 'closed';
    $nowTime = new DateTime("NOW", new DateTimeZone("GMT"));    
    $openTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $open, new DateTimeZone("GMT"));
    $closeTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $close, new DateTimeZone("GMT"));

    // check if the close time is before the opening time       
    if($closeTime <= $openTime){
        $closeTime->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
    }

    if ($nowTime > $openTime && $nowTime < $closeTime){
        $status = 'open';
    }
    return $status;
}

echo OperationHours('09:00AM', '11:30AM');
```

If you are checking the dates with a timezone, set the `GMT`'s to the defined timezones. Otherwise it will have a timezone difference which will show `10:00AM +0300` as `07:00AM +0000 (GMT)` then it'll return `closed`.

Comment: Stll not working i just check this `OperationHours('07:00 AM', '11:30 AM');`

Comment: Are you using a timezone?

Comment: By the way, you have spaces between minutes and letters in your example in the comment.